# Why is my adapter becoming null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, fragmentpageradapter

I'm trying to make a ListFragment that will periodically be updated (Calls to update not shown here, but the update function is). Here's the log cat that I'm seeing:

```
04-05 11:05:44.252: V/QslLogFrag(2690): onCreate()
04-05 11:05:44.256: V/QslLogFrag(2690): onCreateView()
04-05 11:05:44.304: V/QslLogFrag(2690): onActivityCreate()
04-05 11:05:44.612: V/QslLogFrag(2690): null
04-05 11:05:44.736: V/QslLogFrag(2690): com.kd7uiy.qslmapper.QslLogAdapter@5282f55c
04-05 11:05:47.948: V/QslLogFrag(2690): null
```

The last 3 lines lines are all provided in the `updateView` class, which is called externally when there's new data to check. The first two are called essentially automatically, the third one is called by user input.

And the code:

```
public class QslLogFragment extends ListFragment {

    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        Cursor cursor = QslDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).getTableQuery(
                mFilters);
        mAdapter= new QslLogAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        Log.v(TAG,"onActivityCreate()");
    }

    public void updateView() {
        Cursor cursor = QslDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).getTableQuery(
                mFilters);
        Log.v(TAG,""+getListAdapter());
        if (getListAdapter() != null) {
            ((CursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
```

Somehow it seems to me as if the adapter is getting set to null. Note I can still scroll through the ListView without problems, but I can't update it, with a new set of filters. Any ideas what's happening?

Note, QslAdapter extends CursorAdapter, and I'm using the Support Library CursorAdapter.

Here's a list of things I've tried:

1. I have tried just using `setListAdapter` and `getListAdapter`.
2. I have tried not using `getListAdapter`, but just keeping a reference to `mAdapter`.
3. I have verified that there is only one instance of this Fragment.
4. I am not calling `setListAdapter` anywhere.
5. I've verified that `getListAdapter` and `mAdapter` always report the same pointer, or null.

Comment: Either you are assigning `null` to `mAdapter` somewhere, or you are working with different instances of `QslLogFragment`.

Comment: I've explained where the 4 lines came from (Lines 2-4 are all various instances of the `updateView()` method being called.

Comment: @CommonsWare: There is only one QslLogFragment created (LogCat confirms), and I do not have another call to `mAdapter` or `setListView` anywhere else in this function...

Comment: I'd also look at how the `updateView()` is being called, and what state the fragment it in at that time.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Added logging to `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`. They both happen before `onActivityCreate`, and thus don't affect anything.

Comment: Why not use debug an see? Add a breakpoint...

Comment: Interesting... There ARE two fragments, just it's not obvious to me how the second one is being created... Interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @commonsware doesn't mind, I'll put this into an answer for prosperity. Although I'm sure if he has any further insights, he will create a much better answer.

---

I had the feeling you could be dealing with multiple copies of your `QslLogFragment`. I have faced similar problems previously.

In situations like this, it is a good idea to log your method calls, like you have done. Where it is "impossible" for the adapter to be different, that is the hint of having 2 fragments, hence the suggestion to log the fragment as well.

Place extra logs in ALL the Activity & Fragment lifecycle methods to track down the final piece of the puzzle. It may seem like overkill, but you could find some surprises.

---

In the case that I had, which you reminded me of, I had based my code on an Android SDK sample that actually created a new fragment each time I tried to access it. I had not cached any of the fragments that were previously created. So check the code that retrieves (or creates) your fragment.

Here is the code from my `FragmentPagerAdapter` that creates a new fragment each time. This is bad code, and I don't recommend it, but for now it serves its purpose in the demo it comes from.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    // TODO don't create a new fragment each time this is called
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            return new WindFragment();
        }
        // more cases... etc...
        default:
        {
            return new TemperatureFragment();
        }
    }
}
```

This is called every time the user flips to a new page, to show a different fragment. This code caused an issue very similar to yours.

Comment: It is actually an instance of my FragmentPagerAdapter that is the problem. And I see the very line of code that is causing the issue... Sigh. It's similar to your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My issue was very close to Richard's answer, but I'll post a better version of the code.

I have been using a function called [`TabsAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to manage my FragementPager. The default code is this:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }
```

I was setting a listener to the code by using the `getItem` function (My private listener), and thus was actually creating a new fragment!

The solution was to use a `WeakHashMap` to store previous instances of the fragment so I don't re-create them if I don't have to!

```
WeakHashMap<Integer,Fragment> mFragmentMap;

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
    if (mFragmentMap.get(position)==null){
        mFragmentMap.put(position,Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args));
    }
    return mFragmentMap.get(position);
}
```

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I will be implementing when time allows.